# Let a user play his own mp3 files in my music apps?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm learning android and I am creating a music player app. What I want is to prompt the user to choose one of his own music files and then let the user play that file upon interacting with the app.

From the android website i see:

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

But I don't understand the Content Resolver and Provider documentation, and I can't figure out how to ask the user for a file and save the uri of that file in a variable.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Search for Android file picker

Comment: The content resolver only reads specific locations on disk

Comment: So basically I need to implement my own file manager or use an open source one. But what is the simpliest one that you would recommend?